# how to make postgresql result unique

Tags: sql, postgresql, openstreetmap

this is somehow hard to describe, however I have a postgresql 9.1 table (planet_osm_roads).
My query is

```
SELECT
    osm_id, name, highway, way, md5(astext(way)) AS md5
FROM planet_osm_roads
WHERE highway IS NOT NULL
AND md5(astext(way)) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT md5(astext(way))
    FROM planet_osm_roads
    WHERE highway IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY md5
    HAVING count(osm_id) > 1
)
ORDER BY osm_id
```

The result is

```
  osm_id  | name |    highway    |       ...way ...  |               md5                
----------+------+---------------+-------...----...--+----------------------------------
 -1641383 |      | motorway      | 010200...CA96...0 | 04b4336b997e7ea9d99208bd487bbe7d
 -1641383 |      | motorway      | 010200...EC3E...0 | ae945148417ada285130c59277c48a25
 -1641383 |      | motorway      | 010200...7BF6...0 | 5c5a1b8ae40c1b7f24e293a012ad2add
 23133731 |      | motorway_link | 010200...EC3E...0 | ae945148417ada285130c59277c48a25
 31309105 |      | motorway      | 010200...7BF6...0 | 5c5a1b8ae40c1b7f24e293a012ad2add
 49339926 |      | motorway      | 010200...CA96...0 | 04b4336b997e7ea9d99208bd487bbe7d
(6 rows)
```

I want a result that holds 3 rows (one for every md5 hash) and *any* of the other corresponding rows.
So a valid row for "ae945148417ada285130c59277c48a25" may contain osm_id-highway pair of "-1641383" & "motorway" or "23133731" & "motorway_link"- I don't mind and will consider both as correct.

How can I solve this and how is the required operation/technique called? So I know for next time how to call it an what to search for.

Comment: Group by Md5 at the end (before the ORDER BY), and use whatever min() or (max) you prefer on the other columns.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    md5(astext(way)) as md5,
    min(osm_id) osm_id,
    min(name) name,
    min(highway) highway,
    min(way) way
from planet_osm_roads
where highway is not null
group by 1
having count(osm_id) > 1
```

Comment: Your solutions runs faster and produces the same result (for my scenario). Thanks!